# c# Explicitly converting double to long losing accuracy

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion, long-integer

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong here. Why is this happening:

```
long a = (long)((720000 + 144000) * 0.285);
```

Actual value of a: 246,239

Expected value of a: 246,240

Changing the type of 'a' to double and removing the conversion results in the correct value, but I'm writing a program which could result in very large numbers - am I incorrect for trying to use a long as the type?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Obligatory: "What every programmer should know about floating point" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Try `BigInteger a = new BigInteger(((720000 + 144000) * 285)) / 1000;`

Comment: @James Thank you for that article, will give it a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing floating-point imprecision.

`(720000 + 144000) * 0.285` actually computes to `246239.99999999997`.
Reading that as a `double` will round up when printed, but casting to an integral type will always truncate.

Depending on your use case, you may want to use `decimal` or a `BigDecimal` implementation instead of double, or just round.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not allowed to comment I'm going to put an answer here, which really just builds on what SLacks said. If for whatever reason you find that you NEED to use long, there is a C# method Math.Round which will round a value, which would then give you the expected value. Of course rounding isn't always the best option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx